# php parse xml get element same attribute value

Tags: php, xml

I am new in php.

So, i want to parse xml from url like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<all_emp>
<emp_detail>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_1.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_2.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_3.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_1.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_2.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="david"><img>david_1.jpg</img></emp>
</emp_detail>
</all_emp>
```

So, i was try, but in here i has problem:

```
function get_empimg() {
$url = 'https://...emp_test.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$url") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $emp_detail) {
    //do something in here;
    //return img has attribute is John
}
```

}

How to pasre it to get all img with attribute is John?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: put each line in an array, loop over the array where `emp_name="John"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $data2 = <<<'XML'
<all_emp>
<emp_detail>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_1.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_2.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_3.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_1.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_2.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="david"><img>david_1.jpg</img></emp>
</emp_detail>
</all_emp>
XML;


    $doc2 = new SimpleXMLElement($data2);
    return array_map('strval', $this->doc2->xpath("//*[@emp_name='john']/img"));
```

Comment: I was try "return $emp_detail->emp->img;" in foreach. But don't show something.

Comment: Still like that. Does i wrong with "return $emp_detail->emp->img;" in foreach?

Comment: Do `var_dump ((string) $node)`

Comment: But i want all img with attribute is john. Can you fix it?

Comment: In foreach loop, if i use echo $img, it correct. But i use return $img, it only show john_1.jpg. Can you fix it with return?

Comment: with new edit, error in return array_map('strval', $this->doc2->xpath("//*[@emp_name='john']/img"));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150897/discussion-between-akond-and-1234abcd).

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath, Xpath expressions allow for conditions:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//emp[@emp_name="john"]/img') as $img) {
  var_dump($img->textContent);
}
```

Comment: It show null. I was try "return $emp_detail->emp->img;" in foreach. But don't show something.

Comment: Actually I tested it with your XML, and got the expected output. Maybe here is a mistake in how you load the XML or the XML is different (contains a namespace).